# Spotfire combine data below certain count to new categorie

Tags: spotfire

So I have an Excel sheet with a column that contains names and a second column that is a count, how often this name occurs (already done) so my table looks something like this:

```
  Name    Name CNT
  dog     24
  cat     10
  rabbit  3
  mouse   1
  ...
```

My problem is that there are many more values and a lot of them are equal to one, which messes up my pie chart.

Is there a way in Spotfire to combine the ones that are equal to 1 to a new category and the ones between 2 and 10 to another category and so on.

I tried using a custom expression but I can't get it to work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the below table:

[image]

Following these steps:

1. Create "Binned CNT" binned column with the following formula: `BinBySpecificLimits([CNT],1,10,50)`
2. Create a calculated column with the following formula: `case [Binned CNT] 
   when "x ≤ 1" then "Less Than 1" 
   when "1 < x ≤ 10" then "Less Than 10" 
   when "10 < x ≤ 50" then "Less Than 50"
   end`
3. Use those columns to build the below pie chart:

[image]